# Can't get android intent to work as desired

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have a simple app created with the Titanium classic template. To launch the app by clicking a link on a web page I followed the instructions at https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.edtuit.myapp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:label="myapp" android:name="MyappApplication" android:debuggable="false" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <activity android:name=".MyappActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="location" android:path="/"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiTranslucentActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent"/>
    <activity android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.android.TiPreferencesActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize"/>
    <service android:name="com.appcelerator.analytics.APSAnalyticsService" android:exported="false"/>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
```

On a web page I have

```
<a href="intent://location#Intent;package=com.edtuit.myapp;scheme=myapp;end">Try this</a>
```

**Expected result**
When I click the link in the browser on the device I expect it to launch the app "myapp", since it's installed.

**Actual result**
Google Play is launched searching for "my app" (which correctly fails since the app isn't).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: maybe intent://location/#Intent instead of intent://location#Intent

Comment: @tianwei - right on! Many thanks for spotting the missing '/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `intent://location/#Intent` (note the '/' before #Intent).